# Creating User model with Connection (friendships)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have Retailer and Supplier model which inherits from the User model. I been struggling to create Friendship model between them. I want retailer to send friend request to supplier based on @suuplier.account_number. Retailer can only send request if he has account number. So far i have request model which does exactly that. Here is what i have in controller,

```
class RequestsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @retailer = current_user
    @request = @retailer.requests.new
  end

  def create
   @retailer = current_user
   @supplier = Supplier.find_by(params[:account_number])
   @request = @retailer.requests.new(request_params)
   @request.retailer = current_user
   @request.supplier = @supplier
   if @request.save
     redirect_to  retailer_pending_suppliers_path, notice: "Your request has been successfully sent"
   else
     render 'new'
   end
  end


  private

  def request_params
    params.require(:request).permit(:retailer_id, :supplier_id,:account_number ,:status)
  end

end
```

It works but still i am still 100% not confident with what i am doing.This is like a brock wall moment, not sure what to do now. How do i implement friendship with them? what models do i need? and controller?

thank you in advance.

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :generate_account_number
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  def role?
    self.class.name.downcase.to_sym
  end

  def admin?
    self.type == "Admin"
  end
  def supplier?
    self.type == "Supplier"
  end
  def retailer?
    self.type == "Retailer"
  end

  def active_for_authentication?
   super && approved?
 end

 def inactive_message
   if !approved?
     :not_approved
   else
     super # Use whatever other message
   end
 end



private
#this method generates and assigns random account number to the users
  def generate_account_number
    rand_num = SecureRandom.hex(3).upcase
    if self.admin?
      self.account_number = "EGYPT" + "-" + rand_num
    elsif self.retailer?
      self.account_number = "NJ" + "-" + rand_num  + "-" + "RET"
    elsif self.supplier?
      self.account_number = "NJ" +"-" + rand_num + "-"  + "SUP"
    else
      self.account_number = 0
    end
  end


end
```

Retailer Model

```
class Retailer < User
  has_many :stations
  has_many :retailer_suppliers
  has_many :suppliers , through: :retailer_suppliers, as: :connections
  has_many :requests
end
```

Supplier Model

```
class Supplier < User
  has_many :retailer_suppliers
  has_many :retailers, through: :retailer_suppliers
  has_many :requests
end
```

Request model

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :retailer
  belongs_to :supplier

  enum status: [:pending, :approved, :denied]
end
```

I have User type attribute in User model.

Comment: First, it would help to add the user, retailer, and supplier model code to your question considering your questions are mainly about Active Record relationships. Second, I would ditch inheritance unless your models will 100%  share the same data model to make your life a little easier. Because you're likely going to need STI (Single Table Inheritance) and use Active Record's `type` column.

Comment: Yes i have user type attribute in User model. I Updated the question with codes.

Comment: You can have a friendship model similar to your request model that belongs to both retailer and supplier.

Comment: or just use request model with :status=> :approved to track friendship.

Comment: I want to know the approval through supplier point of view. How to make it approve the friendship

Comment: Show supplier the request, when the supplier clicks accept button, you can find the request and update_attributes for it from pending to approved.

Comment: Did you get what you were looking for? if so, I can add it as an answer.

Comment: Yes sure. I think i understand it.

Comment: Can you accept the answer if it was helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a friendship model similar to your request model that belongs to both retailer and supplier

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :retailer
  belongs_to :supplier
end
```

Alternatively, just use request model with :status=> :approved to track friendship.
Show supplier the request, when the supplier clicks accept button, you can find the request and update_attributes for it from pending to approved

Answer (score 0):

I think this railscast might help you: [self referential association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association)

But it's similar to Haider's response. You'll either need another joins table, or modify the requests joins table to indicate a friendship, which I'm guessing will need to store additional metadata.